# How to count the number of files in subdirectories?

Tags: python, directory

I have the following file structure and would like to use python to create a dictionary of the number of files in each folder. The example at the bottom would translate to the following dictionary:

```
{Employee A: {Jan : 3}, {Feb : 2}, Employee B: {Jan : 2}, {Feb : 1}}
```

Does anyone know how to iterate over the directory using os to do this?

```
Employee A
    Jan
        File 1
        File 2
        File 3
    Feb
        File 1
        File 2
Employee B
    Jan
        File 1
        File 2
    Feb
        File 1
```

Comment: What if a directory contains both files *and* subdirectories?  What would you expect the value of the dictionary to be in that case?

Comment: The dictionary in your example isn't valid for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into parsing the output from [os.walk](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/os-walk-python/)

For example:

```
mydict = {}
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk('testdir', topdown=False)
    if len(files)>0:
        mydict[root]=len(files)
print mydict
```

returns

```
{'testdir/EmployeeB/Jan': 2, 'testdir/EmployeeA/Feb': 2, 'testdir/EmployeeB/Feb': 1, 'testdir/EmployeeA/Jan': 3}
```

You could pretty easily parse those keys to generate the nested dictionary that you're looking for.

Comment: Hey John, welcome to StackOverflow.  I know there are some reputation requirements for random things across the site, so you may have hit one of them and answered instead, but if not, your answer is probably better posed as a comment ("Low effort" answers like this will typically get downvoted or flagged).  Just a heads up :)

Comment: @jedwards Thanks.  I did run into the 50 rep requirement for comments but I put a little more effort in to make it a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would let you iterate over all files in a directory and create a list of them. You can modify it as needed:

```
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path

error_log_list = []

def traverse_structure():

  try:
    root = r"C:\\Users\Whatever\Desktop\DirectoryToSearch"
    # Change working directory
    os.chdir(root)

    print("Creating master list of the directory structure...\n")

    # Traverse the folder structure
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(root):

      # Pass over each file
      for file in files:

        absolute_path = os.path.join(folder,file)

        # Create a master file list
        file_paths_list.append(absolute_path)

  except Exception as e:
    error_log_list.append( "Failed to open the root directory specified "+root+"\n Error: "+str(e)+"\n" )

traverse_structure()
```

Comment: I don't think the `os.chdir(root)` is necessary (or even a good idea because it gives the function a likely undesired side-effect) since the current working directory has no effect on `os.walk()`. You also need to define and initialize the `file_paths_list` variable somewhere.

Comment: Explain os.chdir(root) issue in depth please?

Comment: OK. **1.** It's not needed (i.e. doesn't change the `list` the function builds). **2.** Using it means the `traverse_structure()` function has the—quite possibly undesirable—side-effect of changing the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

use os library:

```
import os
parent = os.listdir(path) # return directory files to list
child = []
for x in parent:
    if os.path.isdir(path +'/' + x):
        child.append(os.listdir(path + '/' + x))
    else
        child.append('')
d = dict(zip(parent,child))
print(d)
```

this is the basic logic of making a dictionary out of directories. however this supports 2 levels. I'll leave the n-level part to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With a few minor adjustments the ActiveState Python recipe [Create a nested dictionary from os.walk](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577879-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-oswalk/) can be made to do what you want:

```
try:
    reduce
except NameError:  # Python 3
    from functools import reduce
import os

def count_files_in_directories(rootdir):
    """ Creates a nested dictionary that represents the folder structure
        of rootdir with a count of files in the lower subdirectories.
    """
    dir = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    start = rootdir.rfind(os.sep) + 1
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
        subdir = len(files) if files else dict.fromkeys(files)
        parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir

    return list(dir.values())[0]

startdir = "./sample"
res = count_files_in_directories(startdir)
print(res)  # -> {'Employee A': {'Feb': 2, 'Jan': 3}, 'Employee B': {'Feb': 1, 'Jan': 2}}
```

Note the `./sample` directory is the root directory of a folder structure I created for testing that's exactly like the one shown in your question.